# I have numbers and euro symbols in an excel cell with general format and when I apply sum function to the cells,the sum is not calculated

Tags: excel, sum, format, xls

The excel cell values are like 43€,32€,22€ in each seperate excel cell.These excel cell values are first written as HTML content (HTML table format using <td> and <tr> elements) to a text editor using a Java web application and saved with application/vnd.ms-excel to save it in .xls format.The format of each cell in the excel is General format.On applying SUM function to the cells a sum of zero is only obtained.So it seems like excel is treating the euro symbol as a text character and is not calculating the SUM of the cells.

Comment: It’s not a Java question, is it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way of doing it would be to add in another column that does:

=(NUMBERVALUE(A1)

And then sum that column.

Alternatively you could try:

=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(A1:A100))

As it's an array formula you will need to press control+shift+enter after typing the formula in.